# Trigger not working on SQL import export wizard

Tags: sql

I wrote a trigger on insert of a table. and When i execute insert statement directly in the sql Query window, the trigger is working. But when i try to import data from Excel to Sql, records are getting inserted but the trigger is not working.What could be the possible reason?

Comment: How are you Importing that data ? Are you using Export/Import wizard ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? Firebird? DB2? SQL Server?

Comment: Thru import/export wizard in sql server 2008

Answer (score 1):

by default trigger disabled for bulk insert or import,

we can enable it by,  specify  `FIRE_TRIGGERS`   for a bulk-import operation.

for more [refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thru import/export wizard in sql server 2008

Comment: no Iam not using bulk import or insert,I am using Import/Export data wizard under sql server management studio

Comment: Go to the Advanced Editor, and there should be a property "FastLoadOptions". Specify FIRE_TRIGGERS as an additional option.